# Error installing Highcharts Dashboard on Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I'm trying to implement Highcharts Dashboards on Angular 14.

I'm following [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pc4xsk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) that's in Angular 16 but my assumption is that it should be the same in both versions.

I create a new application in Angular 14:

```
npx ng new angular-app
```

Then install highcharts and the dashboard:

```
cd angular-app
npm install @highcharts/dashboards
npm install highcharts
npm i --save-dev @types/highcharts
```

I add to the component the import:

```
import * as Dashboards from '@highcharts/dashboards/dashboards';
```

When I start the angular application with `ng serve` I get this error:

> Error:
> node_modules/@highcharts/dashboards/es-modules/Dashboards/Plugins/HighchartsTypes.d.ts:1:35
>
> - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'highcharts/es-modules/Core/Globals'.
>   'C:/angular-app/node_modules/highcharts/es-modules/Core/Globals.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/highcharts` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file
>   containing `declare module 'highcharts/es-modules/Core/Globals';`
>
> 1 import type { default as H } from
> 'highcharts/es-modules/Core/Globals';
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have `@types/highcharts` installed, but still getting the error. How to fix this?

Comment: Npm says it's deprecated. Are you importing it correctly and/or have the correct version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are importing all the necessary elements? Just before importing dashboards, you should import Highcharsts. Plus there is no need to add @types/highcharts, the npm page of this package says that it is deprecated, highcharts provide its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/dashboards/dashboards-with-angular

Comment: the example loads the dashboard before highcharts and it works, I'm doing exactly the same as the example, it doesn't matter now, I'm upgrading Angular to version 16, I will test the dashboard with that version

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Angular 14, you will need to downgrade @highcharts/dashboards to version 1.0.1

```
npm i @highcharts/dashboards@1.1.0
```

Comment: It compiles, however when I run the dashboard I get this: `main.ts:11  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Connector type not found. (JSON)
Error: Connector type not found. (JSON)
    at dashboards.js:72:448`

Comment: It appears to be incompatible with your Highcharts version. You can refer to the example I've created here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pk4ivz?file=src%2Fmain.ts for reference.

I updated version highcharts to latest and update @highcharts/dashboards to 1.1.0
highcharts: '11.1.0',
@highcharts/dashboards: '1.1.0'